# How do I set the selection foreground color without using high contrast in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The entry `editor.selectionForeground` in `workbench.colorCustomizations` seems like it should work, but it only applies when your theme is a high contrast theme. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?  I have the same issue.

Comment: Nope. Thanks for reminding me though, I guess I'll ask on some more VSCode-specific forum later